# WSDL level authorization for SOAP service

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, authorization

I have a question regarding authorization for SOAP services. Please note I am asking for authorization, not authentication which I know how to do using WS-Policy specification.

What I would like to do is to define access rights for different SOAP operations. For example: **getMeSomeData** operation is accessible to *simpleUser* but **getMeSomeSecretData** operation is not, but it is accessible to *adminUser*.

I was assuming this is possible since SOAP standard is quite complex. Is there anyone well oriented in SOAP who knows if it is? And if it is possible, could you give me any guidance or article I could read about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my extensive googlig, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way to do this would be with some kind of server integration with whatever the back-end of the soap may be. But this wouldn't be a soap functionality as much as a 'hack' sitting behind it using whatever your authentication layer may happen to be.